# fgetcsv not reading enclosures

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, php-5.5

I am trying to read a CSV line using `fgetcsv`. However it seem not to care at all about enclosures.

Here is what the line looks like:

```
Super Administrator,"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_GROUP_GUEST, ROLE_GROUP_WRITER, ROLE_USER_WRITER, ROLE_USER_GUEST"
```

This is a valid line by CSV standards, and it should return the following with `"` as the enclosure and `,` as the delimiter:

```
$l = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"');
array(
    [0] => 'Super Administrator',
    [1] => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_GROUP_GUEST, ROLE_GROUP_WRITER, ROLE_USER_WRITER, ROLE_USER_GUEST',
);
```

However this is what I get:

```
$l = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"');
array(
    [0] => 'Super Administrator',
    [1] => '"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
    [2] => ' ROLE_GROUP_GUEST',
    [3] => ' ROLE_GROUP_WRITER',
    [4] => ' ROLE_USER_WRITER',
    [5] => ' ROLE_USER_GUEST"',
);
```

So yeah, it seems `fgetcsv` is right-out ignoring completely the enclosure character. I tried to get it working using `fgets` and then `str_getcsv` but the result is the same - `str_getcsv` is most probably called by `fgetcsv` for the CSV conversion anyway.

I figured it could be some sort of regression bug that found its way in the PHP version I'm using, so I'm pasting the result of a `php -v` command here:

```
me@linux:~/$ php -v
PHP 5.5.27-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2015 12:14:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

I believe this is the latest version of PHP5 at the moment I'm writing this. Although I suspect this is some kind of PHP bug, it could also be some installation/configuration problem, hence why I'm publishing this question.

Has anyone already experienced this?
What is the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by Mark Baker, PHP5.5.27-1 is actually the latest revision of PHP5.5 at the time being.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is an attempt with the `bin2hex` function, displayed with a `var_dump`.

Line read `",",","` (2 cells containing only a coma in each cell): `0022002c0022002c0022002c0022000a`.

With `bin2hex('"')` the result is just `22`.

`str_getcsv` still gives me this error though.

Comment: 5.6.11 is the latest version of PHP, not 5.5.27.... that's just the latest revision in the 5.5 branch

Comment: But the str_getcsv() function - which uses the same parsing code internally - works correctly with all versions of PHP back to 5.3.0 (when str_getcsv() was introduced).... are you absolutely certain that the enclosure in your file is a `"` (ASCII 0x22) character, and not a `&quot` or similar

Comment: Thanks for the precision about the PHP revision. About your second comment, yes I am certain of that. Actually I use LibreOffice (an excel ripoff on Ubuntu) and it is the software, not me, that adds the `"`. Even given that, when I open the file in a text editor, the `"` character is displayed, and not anything else.

Comment: Try a `bin2hex()` on the string or use a hex editor to ensure that both `"` are actually ASCII 0x22.

Comment: Works totally fine here (from PHP 5.1.0 on), when I just write your given string into a temp file: http://3v4l.org/6UV1V

Comment: `0022` looks like UTF-16 encoding...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved.

This is what everyone was suspecting: the encoding of the file was messed up. I could not know which encoding this was, but LibreOffice proposed me Unicode whenever I tried to open the CSVs.

I had to open them with nano to realize there was indeed an encoding problem. Gedit, vim or any other tool I had on my computer raised no errors. When opened with nano, an `@` symbol was inserted between every other characters and line feeds were not read correctly.

It seems there are some encodings that are not well supported by `fgetcsv`. To solve the problem, I recreated the files from nano (copy-paste from another tool that did not display the `@`).

Comment: I know this is an older question / answer. Just in case anyone stumbles upon it. ```fgetcsv``` and ```str_getcsv``` will use the internal encoding that PHP uses. One trick is to use something like ```str_getcsv(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents($file), mb_internal_encoding(), 'UTF16'));``` to read the file, which will solve the issue and not require to copy and paste the contents around.