# comma problems while reading CSV file with fgetcsv

Tags: php

I have a CSV file that I am trying to read but some of the field values contain commas and it is throwing off my code. I am using fgetcsv to read the file.

sample of csv file i am reading from

```
"Stock Number","product","title","size","description","price"
"195642","T-Shirt","100% cotton classic fit","XL","Cotton shirts breathe better than clothing made with synthetic materials, and are less prone to retaining odors and losing shape.We offer a wide variety of cotton t-shirts from leading brands such as Fruit of the Loom, Hanes, New Balance, and more.","6.99"
```

The problem is that the values in the description field contain commas.

```
// open file
$txtfile = fopen('../folder/where/file.csv', 'r');

// skip first line (header)
fgetcsv($txtfile, 10000, ",");
while (($line = fgetcsv($txtfile)) !== FALSE) {
}
// close file
fclose($txtfile);
```

In the while loop, I am writing all the information from this CSV file to a larger CSV which get inserted into a database.

The issue I am having is my array gets thrown off by the commas in the description field. For example, this is one of the descriptions

```
"Cotton shirts breathe better than clothing made with synthetic materials, and are less prone to retaining odors and losing shape.We offer a wide variety of cotton t-shirts from leading brands such as Fruit of the Loom, Hanes, New Balance, and more."
```

When my codes reads the file and I try to ouput the value for $line[4] i get

```
Cotton shirts breathe better than clothing made with synthetic materials
```

and then $line[5] which should be price outputs

```
and are less prone to retaining odors and losing shape.We offer a wide variety of cotton t-shirts from leading brands such as Fruit of the Loom
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: It should work, since they're enclosed by quotes. What problem are you having
?

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the issue I am having

Comment: Can you check the code of your second read - `fgetcsv($txtfile,)`

Comment: That is your exact `fgetcsv` call? It should work https://3v4l.org/JE8fK if that is your exact usage, if you have other characters for delimiter/enclosure behavior will be unexpected.

Comment: You might check the encoding of your CSV file. See [fgetcsv not reading enclosures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969287/924299).

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the enclosure character.  I couldn't see anything in the manual that says there's a default enclosure:

```
fgetcsv($txtfile, 10000, ",", '"');
```

Comment: The manual shows this: `fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]]] ) : array`, so the default enclosure is a double quote.

Comment: Not sure why but it's still not working.. I tried fgetcsv($txtfile, 10000, ",", '"'); still getting same output

Comment: I tried removing my first fgetcsv that skips the header to see if it might be conflicting but still getting the same output